# Change Array.prototype in ecmascript (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, node-webkit

I am working on an app using node_webkit combining HTML, CSS and JS. In one part of my app I want to update the Array.prototype so that I can access the last element of an array easily. The code for that is:

```
if (!Array.prototype.last){
    Array.prototype.last = function(){
        return this[this.length - 1];
    };
}
```

If I run only the js-file that works fine and as expected. If I include that js-file into an HTML document it seems that the prototype of the array stays unchanged and I get the error:

> data.last is not a function

Do I have to change something so that I can run my code normally from an HTML file or does that not work at all and I have to take the long way around and access each array with array[array.length - 1]?

The HTML code I use to include the script is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Cocktails.css">
    <title>Cocktails</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/Cocktail.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  /* some elements, that don't use the script yet */
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean change Array.prototype in ecmascript (javascript) I think.; also you haven't posted the HTML document  that you're using to include the script (it may be a load order issue) ... can you share that? Also how are you declaring `data` in the HTML version of the js?

Comment: errr ... share the ACTUAL html, so that the load order can be determined, your question is still not analyzable as it stands.  Because on the face of it it should work.

Comment: Ah never mind I think I know what your issue might be. I'll post an answer

Comment: You are creating `Array.prototype.last()` at the server side but most probably not at the client side. You should check if your Cocktail.js script really includes the conditional definition of `Array.prototype.last()` or check if your `data` is really an array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not calling the function, you'd want to call it like `data.last()` where `data` is some array that you've declared. [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ja8z3697/) of it in action.

Answer (score 0):

In ES5 you need to use `defineProperties` in order to modify the Array prototype in an enumberable way:

Following should work,

```
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, 
       { last: { value: function() { return this[this.length - 1]; } } });
```

More information at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: That didn't change the outcome unfortunately. I think my problem is that I used node.js to create the array. If I use my code and use a normal array that I defined myself it works without any problems. So maybe my other is just not recognized as a "true array" and therefore the change of the prototype has no influence. If I log the prototype of the array I have it says undefined. So I have to look into that, I guess. But thanks for your help